# Tkinter scrollbar is off the screen and doesn't scroll

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas

So I've created a GUI and I need a vertical scrollbar, however the scrollbar seems to be taller than its parent frame, and doesn't scroll. I have no idea why but here's the code I have so far:

```
import tkinter as Tk
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root = Tk.Tk()

RightPane = Tk.Frame(root)
RightPane.grid()

class Graph:
    #Draws and return a placeholder for a graph
    #@param parent is the Tk.Frame parent obj
    #@param title is the (string) title for the graph
    def __init__(self, parent, title=''):
        #Initialise graph
        self.title = title
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(4,4))
        self.plot = self.fig.add_subplot()
        self.plot.set_title(self.title, fontsize=10)
        self.plot.set_ylim(top=1)
        self.plot.set_xlim(right=255)
        self.plot.set_ylabel("Certainty", fontsize=8)
        self.plot.set_xlabel("Pixel Value", fontsize=8)

        #Draw
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=parent)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        self.canvas.draw()

        return

#Result Graphs -------------------------------------------
ResultFrame = Tk.Frame(RightPane)
ResultFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
ResultFrame.grid(row=2, column=2, rowspan=14, padx=(10,0), pady=(10,0), sticky='nwe')

ResultScrollable = Tk.Canvas(ResultFrame)
ResultScrollable.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(5,0), sticky='we')

graphCollection = []
for i in range(10):
    title = 'Certainty that image is digit: {}'.format(i)
    graphCollection.append(Graph(ResultScrollable, title=title))

ResultFrameVbar = Tk.Scrollbar(ResultFrame, orient='vertical', command=ResultScrollable.yview)
ResultFrameVbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nswe')

ResultScrollable.config(yscrollcommand=ResultFrameVbar.set, scrollregion=ResultScrollable.bbox('all'))

root.mainloop()
```

Couldn't find anything on the internet, so any help would really be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The scrollbar should never be taller than its parent.  And if the height of the scrollregion is smaller than that of the canvas, the scrollbar will be disabled.

Comment: The scrollregion of the canvas, after it's been populated, is larger than its parent frame. The scrollbar is not only disabled but it's cutoff.

Comment: Since your code cannot be executed without the missing parts, edit your code to be [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: [here](https://pastebin.com/qj3VL1wQ) is an application based on your posted code with the missing parts: `RightPane` and `Graph(...)`.  The scrollbar is displayed and scrolling is working.

Comment: I've taken your advice and refactored my code to be minimally reproducible, but it still isn't working (I had a look at your paste bin, thanks for taking the time to help). I still don't know why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating canvases (`self.canvas`) inside canvas (`ResultScrollable`) and using `pack()` on those canvases.  So `ResultScrollable.bbox('all')` will not include those canvases.  You should create an internal `Frame` and assocate it with `create_window()`, then put those canvases inside the internal `Frame`:

```
internalFrame = Tk.Frame(ResultScrollable)
ResultScrollable.create_window(0, 0, window=internalFrame, anchor='nw')

graphCollection = []
for i in range(10):
    title = 'Certainty that image is digit: {}'.format(i)
    graphCollection.append(Graph(internalFrame, title=title))
```